# NetSuite Transactions by Department

Tags: netsuite

In NetSuite, on my Income Statement, I see expenses by Department. How does NetSuite know what Department to align the expense to? What field on the transaction does it look at?

I see expenses by department but I'm not sure what field it is looking at in a particular transaction to identify which Department it should align to.

Answer (score 0):

**Department** is a field on transaction. Some times it named as **Cost Center**.
You can check it's JE/Employee with department as well.